# Actionscript 3 , generating random numbers and placing in byte array, faster?

Tags: loops, actionscript-3, flash, random, byte

I am trying to generate large byte arrays of random bytes. Using the below code I can generate 10 million random bytes and place in a byte array in about 4 seconds. 2 seconds for the generation and 2 second to place on the array.

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < reqLength; i++){
    rnd = Math.random() * 255;
    randomBytes.writeByte(rnd);
}
```

Does a faster way exist?

I am generating **int**s because I am creating a byte array of extended ASCII chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a few tweaks I tuned it down from 4s to 0.5s.

```
var aBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray;

// Set the final ByteArray length prior to filling it.
// It saves about 30% of elapsed time.
aBytes.length = 10000000;

// Write 2 500 000 x 4 byte unsigned ints instead of 10 000 000 x 1 bytes.
// You'll get 4 times less operations thus it is about 4 times faster.
for (var i:int = 0; i < 2500000; i++)
{
    // Don't use local variable = less operations.
    aBytes.writeUnsignedInt(Math.random() * uint.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

P.S. There's another funny option, works much faster, like 100ms:

```
var aRaster:BitmapData = new BitmapData(5000, 500, true, 0x000000);
var aBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray;

aRaster.noise(256 * Math.random());
aRaster.copyPixelsToByteArray(aRaster.rect, aBytes);
```

Comment: You're very close to (or is) a correct Answer. Could `writeUnsignedByte` work too? I think Asker wants random single values (of 0-255 range) per byte. _"extended ASCII chars"_ use 8 bits so each one is a single byte (they used the word _"ints"_ maybe to mean non-fraction rather than 4 bytes per value?).

Comment: @VC.One The total amount of operations is a key here, 10M x writeUnsignedByte will be about 4 times slower than 2.5M x writeUnsignedInt. I'm positive that Math.random() * uint.MAX_VALUE will produce 4 x 8 bit random bytes (with the only exception of 0xFFFFFFFF because Math.random() < 1).

Comment: @VC.One but with noise solution it all becomes irrelevant.

Comment: If the `random()` algorithm gives a **5** then `writeUnsignedInt` will give `00 00 00 05` which does not equal 4 uniquely random bytes. It algorithm gives **1400** (from _uint.MAX_VALUE_) then it is beyond max 256 ASCII range. Look at this [**`ASCII chart`**](http://www.ascii-code.com/) this is why **each byte must correspond to an ASCII** char by being within 0-255 range. Hence Asker used `Math.random() * 255;`... Their point about INTS is that they don't want a random non-integer value like 1.777445 as byte value (must be integer/whole numbers only).

Comment: @VC.One The probability of producing 00 00 00 FF or below is 1 / 0x1000000 which, I guess, is pretty close to probability of producing three consequent zeros with a roll of 0 to 255.

Comment: So the solution works great. Thanks. And I now learned some ways to improve other loops I had issue with.

Comment: @VC.One `00 00 00 05` is 4 random bytes. No one said it has to be unique. The same you cannot guarantee calling `Math.random() * 255` 4 times will give you 4 unique values. In theory probability of getting `00 00 00 05` should be the same as probability of  getting something like `FA C4 77 2B`. And if those bits are 4 bytes or 1 uint depends only on how you threat them.

Comment: @PawełAudionysos well with that logic (_ie:_ okay to have sequential duplicate values) then might as well use `writeDouble` and get 8 bytes (not 4) written per time. Then each byte in any of the 8 slots could be read for corresponding ASCII value. If was **AIR** project then using `DomainMemory` would have been fastest way possible but Asker didn't say this. They seem satisfied with given solution.

Comment: @Organis I just woke up... using `uint.MAX_VALUE` is perfectly fine since the larger values would still make each slot have own byte value within 0-255 range. Consider int = 885547222 giving bytes `34 C8 60 D6`. PS : I like the noise solution. Very apt since static/noise is also random by nature.

Comment: Yes, you could write double as well but those are a litter bit different due to floating point nature and I cannot tell you from head it's going to have good distribution :)

Comment: I mean `Number` use some special bits and do use all 64bit value as uint is pure 32bit number.