# Actionscript, improving xor performance?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, xor

I am using the below code to process some large files.

```
var joinedBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
joinedBytes.length = _chunkSize;

for (var i:Number = 0; i < _chunkSize; i++) {
    joinedBytes.writeByte(_xorBytesBuffer[i]^_rndBytesBuffer[i]);
}
```

Its taking about 2.5 seconds to process 10mb of data on a desktop.

Is this normal performance?

Does any way exist to speed it up?

I think that some of the time is writing to the byte array.

EDIT:

_xorBytesBuffer and _rndBytesBuffer are both byte arrays.

Comment: Wait, the question I linked was also written by you. Didn't you understand the answer or something?

Comment: I did, and I had already implemented setting byte array size and not using vars inside the loop. Also the other question was a different scenario. I hoped to get my xor time to be as low as my random byte generation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test everything. I could be wrong somewhere below but...

**ByteArray is faster**

The `[i]` suggest you are using `Vector/Array` using another `ByteArray` for `_xorBytesBuffer` and `_rndBytesBuffer` should speed things up.
You want also operate on larger data i.e. `writeUnsignedInt()` instead of `writeByte()`

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836821/actionscript-3-generating-random-numbers-and-placing-in-byte-array-faster)

**uint is faster vs Number**

And if you only have 10MB, you would like to use `var i:uint` instead of `Number`.

Another thing is you can replace `i++` wit `++i` though I did't really test  if this has much impact - I only heard that it's faster.

**Remove additional steps.**

You could even try something like:

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < _chunkSize;) {
    joinedBytes.writeByte(_xorBytesBuffer[i]^_rndBytesBuffer[i++]);
}
```

Please let us know it `_rndBytesBuffer[i++]` makes any difference ;)

Wait, I just said to not use indicies but another ByteArrays... Well If you still want to try above still let us know how it performs ;)

**Make sure your condition check is as simple as possible.**

Make sure you have something like `var _chunkSize:uint` instead of

```
function _chunkSize(){return something;}
```

Comment: I am now using int, and i++ inside the xor, it took 60mb of data from 15 seconds to 14. On further testing it seems that 60% of the loop execution time is _xorBytesBuffer[i]^_rndBytesBuffer[i] and the other 40% is writeByte.

Comment: why don't you use `b.writeUnsignedInt()` as in previous question? That has probably the biggest impact.

Comment: I didn't fully understand that part, when tried it outputted more data than it should so I think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: And how much data do you need to process? I you have large amount of data you should consider writing that part in some language like c++.

Comment: A couple of GB maximum. So its currently 20+ minutes on decent desktop hardware.

Comment: because if you want to use `writeUnsignedInt(joinedBytes)` you should also need have do `_xorBytesBuffer.readUnsignedInt()^_rndBytesBuffer.readUnsignedInt()` and your `_chunkSize` then goes to `_chunkSize/4`

Comment: I don't know how much time you can accept but If you want  cipher  couple GB of data then flash was not designed to do such tings and probably C++/Assembly is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this is just a project to learn with and not something I need to be perfect in any way. I appreciate AS is not ideal for this situation.

Comment: I you are interested in this - did you see [Using encryption with SQL databases](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS8AFC5E35-DC79-4082-9AD4-DE1A2B41DAAF.html)